# Неперекрываемое окно на GTK(статус-бар || панель)

Tags: linux, gtk, gtk3, xlib

Я хочу написать собственный статус-бар, используя GTK.

Каким образом, используя средства GTK или Xlib, я могу сообщить оконному менеджеру или среде рабочего стола о том, что мою панель нельзя перекрывать другими окнами?

Пока что нагуглил метод gdk_window_set_keep_above(), но не уверен что он мне на 100% поможет. В документации к этому методу(https://developer-old.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gdkwindow.html#method-gdkwindow--set-keep-above) написано что некоторые оконные менеджеры его игнорируют.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите на этот ответ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806203/how-to-make-a-toplevel-perform-like-a-panel там автор утверждает, что он смог это сделать.

Также, посмотрите как эту проблему решают в xfce-panel (это собственно то, что Вы хотите сделать) - https://github.com/xfce-mirror/xfce4-panel/commit/79d22c3b4455b5f72ae20299c2a72e5217628b3d - в этом коммите они как раз делают опциональной поддержку "on top".

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то, что мне было нужно